# Updating a row in the same SQL table based on information from another table - MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have two tables, a reference table and a details table.  The reference table lists current production step of an order paired with the next step, as so:

**Reference Table**

```
Current_Step      | Next_Step          |  ID
-------------------------------------------------
Step 1            | Step 2             | 1
Step 2            | Step 3             | 2
Step 3            | Step 4             | 3
```

I also have a order details table:

```
Order_ID  | Step_ID  | Start_Date | Planned_End | Complete_Date | Planned_Duration
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000      | 1        | 1/1/2013   | 1/3/2013    | 1/3/2013      | 2
1000      | 2        |            |             |               | 3
1000      | 3        |            |             |               | 8
```

In this table, each step for the order exists, but has a blank start date and planned end date.

I'm attempting to build a query that:

- Looks for every item that has a complete date of today
- Find the Next_Step associated with that item for the same Order_ID in the table
- If the Start_Date is blank, updates the Start_Date to today, and adds Planned_Duration days to the start date to calculate a Planned_End date

I'm able to do parts of it individually, but I'm having a hard time bringing it all together into a single query/stored procedure.

I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Today datetime

select @Today = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

update od2 set
    start_date = @Today,
    planned_end = dateadd(dd, od2.planned_duration, @Today)
from order_details as od
    inner join reference_table as rt on rt.current_step_id = od.step_id
    inner join order_details as od2 on od2.order_id = od.id and od2.step_id = rt.next_step_id
where
    od.complete_date = @Today and od2.start_date is null
```

Comment: the question is tagged with SQL Server 2005, so you can't use `DATE` data type

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
 select 
    n.orderId
 from
    refernce_table as r
    inner join order_details as p
        on r.current_step = p.step_id
    inner join order_details as n
        on r.next_step = n.step_id
 where 
     p.complete_date is not null
     and n.start_date is null
```

this gives you previous steps as p and next steps as n.. filter them as you need

here i am saying give me the orders where the previous step is complete and the next step is not started . i think ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for SQL Server 2005):

```
UPDATE  n SET
        Start_Date =  CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),
        Planned_end = DATEADD(dd, n.Planned_Duration,  CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112))
FROM    order_details AS d
JOIN    refernce_table AS r ON d.step_id= r.ID
JOIN    order_details AS n ON n.step_id = CONVERT(int, REPLACE(r.Next_Step, 'Step ',''))
AND     d.order_id = n.order_id
WHERE   d.Complete_Date =  CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112)
AND     N.Start_date is null;
```